# Implementing any_of in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, lambda, c++20

I've decided to implement Python's [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) in C++. I've gone about this using templates to allow multiple types of data to be passed, instead of overloading the function multiple times. This is my first time using templates so I would really like feedback about my usage of them. I'm also fairly new with references and pointers, so I would like some criticism about my use of them as well. Of course, anything else is on the table and appreciated.

While writing this program, I realized [`std::any_of`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/any_of/) existed. So yes, I do know there's already a built-in method for this.

`any.hpp`

```
#ifndef ANY_HPP_INCLUDED
#define ANY_HPP_INCLUDED

/**
 * @author Ben Antonellis
**/

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

/**
 * Returns True if any of the elements meet the callback functions parameters.
 * 
 * @param elements - A list of elements.
 * @param callback - Callback function to invoke on each element.
 * 
 * @return bool - True if parameters are met, False otherwise.
**/
template <typename List, typename Function>
bool any(List &elements, Function *callback) {
    for (auto element : elements) {
        if (callback(element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

#endif
```

And here's how I'm testing this function:

**main.cpp**

```
/**
 * @author Ben Antonellis
**/

#include "Any.hpp"

int main() {

    std::vector<double> doubleElements = {-1.0, -2.0, -3.0};
    std::vector<std::string> stringElements = {"Hello", "Goodbye", "Testing 123"};

    auto doubleFunc = [] (double number) {
        return number < 0;
    };
    auto stringFunc = [] (std::string string) {
        return string.length() >= 5;
    };

    /* Test Any Implementation */
    if (any(doubleElements, *doubleFunc)) {
        std::cout << "(any) Double Success." << std::endl;
    }
    if (any(stringElements, *stringFunc)) {
        std::cout << "(any) String Success." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you would like to compile and run, below is the script I'm using to compile and run this program.

**run.sh**

```
# Compile c++ program to .o file #
g++ -std=gnu++2a -c main.cpp # gnu++2a = Working draft for ISO C++ 2020 with GNU extensions #

# Compile .o file to executable #
g++ main.o -o app

# Run the executable #
./app

# Delete executable and .o files after running #
rm app main.o
```

Comment: Off-topic, but note that [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com) is a more up-to-date and (in general) high-quality community-driven documentation than cplusplus.com as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Agreed, I use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) almost exclusively. It ain't pretty, but it gets the job done :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The algorithm looks correct.

Regarding the function signature, I'd make three changes:

1. You're not modifying elements, so take it by constant reference rather than reference.
2. You don't need to specify a pointer to Function, Function is already a template parameter, and non-pointers could be valid (ex: a class with a () operator).
3. "callback" isn't a very useful name for this case.  "predicate" would be better.

While this form is fine, I'd also include a version that takes a start/end iterator instead of a container.

Also, there's no reason to include vector or iostream in any.hpp - only include things that are necessary.

For completeness in the testing method, you should also test with an empty collection, and a collection with no matches.

Comment: Although predicate is more specific, "callback" seems to have become a very common term to refer to the function passed to a higher-order function, regardless of its role in the algorithm.

Comment: @Barmar No, predicate implies both argument list and return type, and as such is idiomatic.

Comment: See here for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter @CaptainGiraffe

Comment: @Barmar: That also says predicate in the description. Callback is a broad term, as you note, and in C++ _predicate_ is quite consistently used for any `bool (T)` functor.

Comment: @Barmar In they context of C++ (as well as other languages!) I'd expect a callback to be invoked predominantly for its side-effect. By contrast, and in addition to the other comments, I expect a predicate to be (logically) side-effect free.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not saying that predicate is wrong, I just took exception to the point that callback is a poor name for the parameter, since it's a common, although less specific, term for this. And I gave an example of a well known documentation site that uses it. I also just checked, and the EcmaScript 2020 spec calls it `callbackfn`.

Comment: @Barmar C++ terminology is quite different from other programming languages ... In C++, "callback" is generally redefined to mean functions / function objects registered in event managers to react to certain events, or in similar contexts where the registered operations are invoked by external signals and mainly for side-effect; [the one in `ios_base`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/register_callback) is an example. Using `callback` when `predicate` is more appropriate sounds very anti-C++ish to my (possibly biased) C++-trained ears.

Answer (score 18):

I think you did a pretty good job as a [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner). In addition to what Errorsatz said:

- Consider making `element` a const reference to prevent unnecessary copying: `const auto& element : elements`
- You missed `#include <string>` in the test file.
- `std::endl` flushes the buffer and causes performance degradation; use `\n` instead unless you need the flushing behavior.
- Try to avoid compiler-specific nonstandard extensions, because they make your program non portable. `-std=c++20 -pedantic-errors` makes g++ go into conforming mode and disables these nonstandard extensions. It is also unnecessary to separate the compiling step from the linking step — g++ does it for you. And remember to turn on warnings! They help you spot many logical bugs in your program. My usual compiling directive looks like this:

  ```
  g++ main.cpp -o app -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors
  ```

  (Sometimes I turn on `-ftrapv` to avoid inadvertently relying on integer overflow behavior as well.)

Answer (score 3):

I see some of the issues include copying the data and passing by reference or const reference. Might I suggest following the STL's method of using iterators?

Your any function is essentially [std::find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) using a container instead of iterators.

Rewriting it to use `std::find_if` reveals the differences:

```cpp
template<typename List, typename Predicate>
bool any(List&& list, Predicate&& pred)
{
    return std::find_if(
                        begin(list),
                        end(list), 
                        std::forward<Predicate>(pred))
           != end(list);
}
```

Some of the issues I see with your initial implementation are:

- Passing list as a non-const reference. This is fixed as in MSalters answer and shown above.
- Passing the predicate as a pointer. We're using templates here, so let the predicate be anything it wants without being converted to a function pointer.
- Reimplementing `std::find_if` (though I understand wanting to learn!)

My recommended method of implementing this without `std::find_if` is:

```cpp
template<typename List, typename Predicate>
bool any(List&& list, Predicate&& pred)
{
    for(auto&& element : list) {
        if(pred(element))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your header guard is:

```
#ifndef ANY_HPP_INCLUDED
```

The style I most commonly see in modern code is

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_ANY_HPP
```

(or, just leave off the `_HPP` part). The reason is that *technically*, C and C++ reserve all uppercase names matching `E[A-Z].*` to the implementation, for macros like `EINVAL` and `EPERM`. Of course in practice your implementation won't have a macro named `EGG_HPP_INCLUDED`; but it's theoretically safer, and just as easy, to write `INCLUDED_EGG_HPP` and eliminate that consideration entirely. Names beginning with `I` aren't reserved to the implementation.

---

```
template <typename List, typename Function>
bool any(List &elements, Function *callback) {
```

You should certainly pass `elements` by const reference, since you aren't planning to modify it. Consider this use-case:

```
std::vector<int> getPrimesBetween(int, int);
bool isOdd(int);
bool b = any(getPrimesBetween(3, 100), isOdd);
```

Since `getPrimesBetween(3, 100)` is an rvalue expression, your template taking by lvalue reference won't work.

---

Similarly, taking `callback` by pointer is weird. Take callbacks either by value (STL style) or by const reference (to avoid unnecessary copying). Consider:

```
std::vector<int> primes;
auto isOdd = [](int x) { return x % 2 != 0; };
bool b = any(primes, isOdd);
```

This won't compile with your template, because `decltype(isOdd)` is a class type (an unnamed lambda class type) that doesn't pattern-match against `Function *`.

You solve this in a very strange way that is nevertheless kind of cute:

```
bool b = any(primes, *isOdd);
```

What you probably *meant* to type here was `&isOdd`, not `*isOdd`. However, the latter also works, because the lambda type has no `operator*`, and therefore it undergoes implicit conversion to a scalar type so it can use the built-in `*`. The only implicit conversion available is the implicit conversion to a function-pointer type. So you convert the lambda to a function pointer, dereference the pointer to get a function *reference*, and then pass that function by value to your template, which decays it back into a function pointer, which happily pattern-matches against `Function *`.

Observe the difference between `&isOdd` and `*isOdd` here: https://godbolt.org/z/ehdbvw

Specifically, `&isOdd` and `&isEven` have different types, but `*isOdd` and `*isEven` have the same type.

By taking only function pointers, you're also preventing your template from ever being used with stateful lambdas:

```
auto isDivisibleBy(int n) { return [n](int x) { return x % n != 0; }; }
bool b1 = any(primes, isDivisibleBy(3));  // ERROR during deduction
auto isThreeven = isDivisibleBy(3);
bool b2 = any(primes, *isThreeven);  // ERROR no such operator
bool b3 = any(primes, &isThreeven);  // ERROR during instantiation
```

---

```
    for (auto element : elements) {
```

Since you don't intend to modify the elements, you might take them by `const&`; but actually you *should* take them by `auto&&`, because [`auto&&` Always Works](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/15/autorefref-always-works/).

---

Putting it all together, you'd end up with something like

```
template<class List, class Function>
bool any(const List& elements, const Function& callback) {
    for (auto&& element : elements) {
        if (callback(element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Personally I might use the names `Range`, `Callable`, and `pred[icate]` in place of `List`, `Function`, and `callback`... but I guess just putting that in writing makes it pretty plain which one of us has been steeped too long in the unhealthy waters of STL jargon. :)

Comment: @Linny: I just blogged the `*isOdd` quirk here — https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/03/31/asterisk-and-ampersand/

Answer (score 2):

Errorsatz already mentioned the `Functor` type, but I'd like to argue for [`Functor&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548614/should-templated-functions-take-lambda-arguments-by-value-or-by-rvalue-reference).

As for testing, this is a case where you **literally** want to test edge cases. I.e. where the first or only the last element has the desired property. Two additional special cases to test would be a single element, matching or not matching. ([Zero-one-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) rule of thumb; your tests both have many=3 elements)

Comment: I don't think using perfect forwarding is appropriate in this case - the function object is called multiple times. Using a forwarding reference to capture rvalues and call the function object unforwarded (i.e., as an lvalue) is fine though.

Answer (score 2):

I see one place where you could use a C++ comment:

```
    /* Test Any Implementation */
```

Because this comment only spans one line, I generally prefer to use a C++ comment instead:

```
    // Test Any Implementation
```